# How to send Email sending without html format

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I send email in rails using mailer.It send successfully.But the way it send is not proper.It is sending in html tags like that

```
Sent mail to xxx (3.6ms)
Date: Mon, 09 Nov 2015 14:53:15 +0500
From: from@example.com
To: xxx
Message-ID: <56406d0b15b8e_6f03f8d3408607861097@des-0071.mail>
Subject: Password Reset
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
<body>
<p>Hello </p>

<p>Someone has requested a link to change your password. You can do this through the link below.</p>
<p><a href="/api/password_edit.LnWq8Y018rU0MGGZpDfHjA">Change my password</a></p>

<p>If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.</p>
<p>Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

File is password_reset.html.erb

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: Want to send it without these html tags and proper link

Comment: It seems that you have run above using rails console. Did you try not in console?

Comment: Yes trying on console

Comment: I added answer below, I hope that would help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The email client will render those tags once the email is received by the user and you will not see any of them. An email template is treated very much like a View in Rails. if you take everything between `<html>` and `</html>` and save it in a file and open it in a browser, that's what the email will look like for the user.

Also you want to send an absolute path in your email link, that is a relative link you have right now and if the user clicks it outside your website (from an email client) it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

In rails console, you can see the html tag actually. But in the real email you could not see those HTML tags. Try to run not using console but run actually how do you want it to call. Use [mailcatcher](http://mailcatcher.me/)gem to see real results of the email.

In short, you can install and run like this:

1. `gem install mailcatcher`
2. run `mailcatcher` to your bash.
3. Go to browser: `http://localhost:1080/`

Then you can see like this [image](http://f.cl.ly/items/3w2T1p0F3g003b2i1F2z/Screen%20shot%202011-06-23%20at%2011.39.03%20PM.png).